# passing shader values to global variables

Tags: three.js, shader

Am using this vertex shader in an three.js shadermaterial

```
script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

  uniform sampler2D map;
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {

    vUv = uv;
    vec4 color = texture2D( map, vUv );

    float r=color.r;
    float g=color.g;
    float b=color.b;                    


    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix ;
  }

</script>
```

the question is: how can I pass the values of r,g and b to a global variables?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the common way to get results from a fragment shader is to render your scene to a texture and then read (in your javascript program) from this texture the data you want to manipulate. Look for 'render to texture' in the documentations.

Example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Comment: Thanks @Popov do you know how can I read the data from the texture? specifically de color of each vertex

Comment: You can try the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475209/three-js-get-data-from-three-webglrendertarget.