# THREE.js read pixels from GPUComputationRenderer texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

I have been playing with GPUComputationRenderer on a modified version of [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html) which modifies the velocity of interacting boids using GPU shaders to hold, read and manipulate boid position and velocity data.

I have got to a stage where I can put GPU computed data (predicted collision times) into the texture buffer using the shader.  But now I want to read some of that texture data inside the main javascript animation script (to find the earliest collision).

Here is the relevant code in the render function (which is called on each animation pass)

```
//... GPU calculations as per original THREE.js example
gpuCompute.compute();   //... gpuCompute is the gpu computation renderer.           
birdUniforms.texturePosition.value = gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( positionVariable ).texture;
birdUniforms.textureVelocity.value = gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( velocityVariable ).texture;

var xTexture = birdUniforms.texturePosition.value;//... my variable, OK.

//... From http://zhangwenli.com/blog/2015/06/20/read-from-shader-texture-with-threejs/
//... but note that this reads from the main THREE.js renderer NOT from the gpuCompute renderer.
//var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height * 4);               
//var gl = renderer.getContext();
//gl.readPixels(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array( WIDTH * WIDTH * 4);   //... OK.

//var gl = gpuCompute.getContext();//... no getContext function!!!

//... from Nick Whaley here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475209/three-js-get-data-from-three-webglrendertarget
//WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels ( renderTarget, x, y, width, height, buffer )

gpuCompute.readRenderTargetPixels ( xTexture, 0, 0, WIDTH, WIDTH, pixelBuffer ); //... readRenderTargetPixels is not a function!
```

As shown in the code I was "wanting" the `gpuCompute` renderer object to provide functions such as `.getContext()` or `readRenderTargetPixels()` but they do not exist for `gpuCompute`.

---

EDIT:

Then I tried adding the following code:-

```
//... the WebGLRenderer code is included in THREE.js build
myWebglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();                            
var myRenderTarget = gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( positionVariable );             
myWebglRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels ( 
        myRenderTarget,  0, 0, WIDTH, WIDTH, pixelBuffer );
```

This executes OK but pixelBuffer remains entirely full of zeroes instead of the desired position coordinate values.

---

Please can anybody suggest how I might read the texture data into a pixel buffer? (preferably in THREE.js/plain javascript because I am ignorant of WebGL).

Comment: That will be hard to accept, but... you can't read back to system memory regular texture pixels in OpenGL, only from FrameBuffer Object (FBO) or RenderBuffer. To achieve that you have to use something else then `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` as render target. I don't know what in three.js will help you in that case, but you certainly need to modify `gpuCompute` code.

Comment: @VallyN Thanks for the explanation and advice.  Tinkering with `gpuCompute` is beyond my current skills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This answer is out of date. See link at bottom**

The short answer is *it won't be easy*. In WebGL 1.0 there is no easy way to read pixels from floating point textures which is what `GPUComputationRenderer` uses.

If you really want to read back the data you'll need to render the GPUComputationRenderer floating point texture into an 8bit RGBA texture doing some kind of encoding from 32bit floats to 8bit textures. You can then read that back in JavaScript and look at the values.

See [WebGL Read pixels from floating point render target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981163/webgl-read-pixels-from-floating-point-render-target)

Comment: Many thanks for the steer and link. My WebGL is non-existent so it will probably be a long time before I can dive further into this.

Comment: I'm the coauthor of GPUComputationRenderer. Now the water simulation example includes reading of texture data as floating point (used to simulate tennis balls on the surface)

Comment: @yombo I'm seeing in Chrome Performance Tab that the WebGL API seems to block on the render alternating between the bulk of the time being taken under `readPixels` or `checkFramebufferStatus`. I guess that is the drawback of these APIs, and it's ok that the profile shows this? I'm encountering the same behavior with something I'm working on, and I am hoping you know a bit more about the implementation in the browser. performance seems not too negatively affected, it's just interesting to me that the GPU seems to be doing the rendering work "under" those GL calls.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the long delay. I've not logged in in SO for a long time.

In the example of water with tennis balls,
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=water#webgl_gpgpu_water

The height of the water at the balls positions is read back from the GPU.

An integer 4-component texture is used to give a 1-component float texture.

The texture has 4x1 pixels, where the first one is the height and the other 2 are the normal of the water surface (the last pixel is not used)

This texture is computed and read back for each one of the tennis balls, and in CPU the ball physics is performed.

Comment: Thanks for the insights which will be very useful when I find time to take this project up again!