# How to get pixels from computed texture in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to compute a multidimensional array of data, and I think GPUComputationRenderer is a good solution for that.

I started from an example project and was stuck on this:

```
var gpuCompute = new GPUComputationRenderer( 100, 100, this.renderer );

var dtPosition = gpuCompute.createTexture();
var dtVelocity = gpuCompute.createTexture();

var velocityVariable = gpuCompute.addVariable( 
   "textureVelocity", 
   this.compFragmentShader(), 
   dtVelocity 
);
var positionVariable = gpuCompute.addVariable( 
   "texturePosition", 
   this.compVertexShader(),   
   dtPosition 
);

gpuCompute.setVariableDependencies( 
   velocityVariable, 
   [ positionVariable, velocityVariable ] 
);
gpuCompute.setVariableDependencies( 
   positionVariable, 
   [ positionVariable, velocityVariable ] 
);

gpuCompute.init();

gpuCompute.compute();

//TODO: Get pixels from resulting texture
```

I had read some examples on three.js:

- https://threejs.org/examples/?q=water#webgl_gpgpu_water
- https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gp#webgl_gpgpu_birds
- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/misc/GPUComputationRenderer.js

Also, I had read this stack overflow [THREE.js read pixels from GPUComputationRenderer texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736203/three-js-read-pixels-from-gpucomputationrenderer-texture?rq=1) but there is no solution, only links to webGL.

Am I missing something?
Please provide an example or describe what am I doing wrong

Comment: Maybe [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels)?

Comment: Hello @gman! I tried this. it just returns array filled with 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't HAVE to get it back.

The WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels doesn't work because the GPUComputationRenderer does not render to the WebGLRenderer itself. It uses WebGLRenderTargets (something like an offscreen 'invisible' canvas).

The stack overflow thread you pointed to says it all; it's not really possible. Unless you do some weird math and convert/pack the float texture to integer textures.. So, once you transfer your data to the gpu/glsl side, it's near impossible to get it back to the cpu/javascript side.

Like i said, you don't HAVE to get it back. I believe I see in your code that you are familiar with vertex/fragment shaders? I've done this before with point clouds.

You can pass the dtPositions(or dtPositions.texture perhaps) as an uniform into a shadermaterial on your 'display' mesh and use the shader to get the position out of the texture and move the vertex to that position.